# Retaining the value of root in a binary search tree using java

Tags: java, recursion, tree, root, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to code a binary search tree using java and currently I run into the problem of not being able to retain my value of root after calling certain methods.

Right now I'm writing the add() and height() methods which look like this:

```
public boolean add(E x) {
    BinaryNode<E> temp = null;
    if (root == null) {
        root = new BinaryNode<>(x);
        temp = root;
        return true;
    } else {


        BinaryNode<E> node = root;

        if(root.equals(x)){
            root = temp;
            return false;
        }

        if (node.element.compareTo(x) < 0) {
            if (node.left == null) {
                node.left = new BinaryNode<E>(x);
                return true;
            }
            root = node.left;
            add(x);
        }
        if (node.element.compareTo(x) > 0) {
            if (node.right == null) {
                node.right = new BinaryNode<E>(x);
                return true;
            }
            root = node.right;
            add(x);
        }
        root = temp;
    }
    return false;
}
```

A node is described by the following class:

```
    static class BinaryNode<E> {
    E element;
    BinaryNode<E> left;
    BinaryNode<E> right;

    private BinaryNode(E element) {
        this.element = element;
    }
}
```

Now, I have BinaryNode root; as an attribute in my BST class. The purpose of this attribute is that it allows me to have methods without input parameters by recursively altering the value of root (for educational purposes only, I will not cheat here and use input parameters even though it might be easier).

The add(E x) method seems to be working properly but the problem is that the method height() also alters the attribute root, so when I use add(E x) after calling height() it doesn't work since I've yet to figure out how to retain the value of root through the height() method.

height() currently looks like this:

```
public int height() {

    if(root == null){
        return 0;           
    } else {

        int lefth = 0;
        int righth = 0;

        BinaryNode<E> node = root;
        if(root.left != null){
            root = root.left;
            lefth = height();
        }
        if(root.right != null){
            root = root.right;
            righth = height();
        }

        root = node;

        if(lefth > righth){
            return lefth+1;
        } else {
            return righth+1;
        }
    }
}
```

I know for sure that this method is faulty since it recursively changes the value of root (which is intended) but it fails in "resetting" the value of root to the actual root of the whole tree, if you know what I mean.

Inside my main method I wrote a couple lines of code to test if the two methods work and I'm quite sure that the add(E x) method works but the height() certainly doesn't work correctly. The purpose of height() is of course to return the height of the tree.

My main method has this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinarySearchTree<Integer> tree = new BinarySearchTree<>();

    int a = 10;
    int b = 11;
    int c = 9;
    int d = 9;
    int e = 5;
    int f = 8;

    System.out.println("Adding " + a + " " + tree.add(a) + " \tHeight: " + tree.height());
    System.out.println("Adding " + b + " " + tree.add(b) + " \tHeight: " + tree.height());
    System.out.println("Adding " + c + " " + tree.add(c) + " \tHeight: " + tree.height());
    System.out.println("Adding " + d + " " + tree.add(d) + " \tHeight: " + tree.height());
    System.out.println("Adding " + e + " " + tree.add(e) + " \tHeight: " + tree.height());
    System.out.println("Adding " + f + " " + tree.add(f) + " \tHeight: " + tree.height());

}
```

And it outputs the following lines into to console:

```
Adding 10 true  Height: 1
Adding 11 true  Height: 2
Adding 9 true   Height: 2
Adding 9 false  Height: 0
Adding 5 true   Height: 1
Adding 8 true   Height: 2
```

So, as it seems, my add(E x) is functioning properly since I'm not allowed to add duplicates. However I really don't know how to code height() correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've not gone through the code in detail but it looks/sounds like you are mixing temporary/local variables and class ones.

You are modifying the root node when you call `height` and this actually changes the globally scored one.

What you should instead do is have a local variable within the method that stores the current root and uses that to search, rather than modifying the global one.

i.e.

```
public int height() {
    Node searchNode = root;
    if(searchNode == null){
```

Now you do all the processing using searchNode without corrupting the global record of the root node.

Comment: Hey Tim! I actually tried doing that but the problem I encountered then was that the add(E x) and similarly the height() would cause a stack overflow since they're not actually changing the global root attribute. The fact that the method is called within the method itself seems to make it so that one has to alter the global attribute since I'm not using input parameters. I just need to figure out a way to let root have the same value before and after a method call. Within the method, however, it seems as though root must be altered in order to achieve proper recursion.

Comment: I forgot to mention that since the method runs itself over and over it will always replace that Node searchNode = root; with the temporary root - that's essentially the problem I'm having.